# solving a tie when sorting a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing lists, with the same number of elements each.

```
to_sort={'a':np.array([1,1,3]),'b':np.array([5,4,5])}
```

I would like to add a new key, 'rank', which is contain the index of the sorted dictionary according to 'a', and in case of a tie, according to 'b'.
I can do:

```
to_sort['a'].argsort()
```

and get the sorting indexes. However, in case of a tie as in the example I would get:

```
np.array([1,3,3]).argsort()
Out[17]: array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Now I would like to rank these sorting indexes using the values of 'b'.
e.g. desired output -> `[1,0,2]` and not `[0,1,2]`.
Python native solution preferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.lexsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) for this:

```
res = np.lexsort((to_sort['b'], to_sort['a']))

# array([1, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Note the reversed sort order for this function, i.e. the above code sorts first by `a`, then by `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found it to be relatively easy also with pandas

```
custom_ranked=pd.DataFrame(to_sort).sort_values(['a','b'],
    ascending=[False,True]).loc[:,['a','b']]
```